# Representing $GL(2)$ as dilations $\times$ shears $\times$ $SO(2)$

Tags: group-theory

In this paper[1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.5848.pdf) in section 2, it is stated that one can write the GL(4,R) using the generator of dilation (1 parameter), those of shears (9 parameters) and the Lorentz generator (6 parameters).

Here, I am only interested in the 2D case. I am trying to represent GL(2,R) as the multiplication of 3 groups:  dilations $\times$ shears $\times$ $SO(2)$, but I am having trouble

---

My attempt is as follows

Let $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ be represented as follows:

$$
\exp \left( \begin{bmatrix}
a+x & -b+y\\
b+y & a-x
\end{bmatrix} \right) = \exp \left( \begin{bmatrix}
a & 0\\
0 & a
\end{bmatrix} \right) \exp \left( \begin{bmatrix}
x & y\\ y & -x
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -b\\
b & 0
\end{bmatrix} \right)
$$

I am able to factor out the dilations, but my problem is that the two matrix in $\exp \left( \begin{bmatrix}
x & y\\ y & -x
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -b\\
b & 0
\end{bmatrix} \right)$ do not commute. And therefore I cannot use my representation of GL(2,R) to write it as  dilations $\times$ shears $\times$ $SO(2)$.

What is the correct matrix representation to use to be able to write GL as  dilations $\times$ shears $\times$ $SO(2)$?

Comment: This doesn't make sense: $\mathbb{R}$ is not a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ (at least, considering it as the set of diagonal matrices), and shear matrices and orthogonal matrices generally don't commute. You might be looking for something similar to the Iwasawa decomposition of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ or $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$, though.

Comment: You didn't share the paper . . .

Comment: @anomaly In the paper I linked they claim to do it in $GL_4(\mathbb{R})$. Is $GL_4(\mathbb{R})$ special? its section 2 equation 2.7

Comment: Equations 2.6 and 2.7 in the paper are basically taking coset representatives, not expressing $GL_4(\mathbb{R})$ as an inner product. (The subgroup they're considering is also $SO(3, 1)$, not $SO(4)$.)